# How do i ensure that my all device drivers are properly installed?

Tags: drivers, devices

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Asus [H-97 Pro Gamer mobo](https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/H97PRO_GAMER/) with [Intel i3 4130](http://ark.intel.com/.../Intel-Core-i3-4130-Processor-3M-Cache-3_40-GHz) 3.4ghz in-addition sata 6gb/s 1TB HDD

How do i ensure that my all device drivers are properly installed?

Comment: Do your devices work? If yes, then the drivers are installed correctly.

Comment: i just wanna check whether they are working on their best specification using drivers or not..

Comment: I think this may be what you want https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo but I am not to sure. It can test and benchmark your hardware, install it with `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`